# BindingSource filter empty cell

Tags: c#, winforms, filter, datagridview

I want to filter my DataGridView with BindingSource.

I actually know how to do that.

But when I try to filter all the blank cells in the column, I don't get that.

Here my code:

```
 BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
 bs.DataSource = Dgv_Data_List.DataSource;
 //bs.Filter = "Test like '" + string.Empty + "%'";   <-- do not work
 //bs.Filter = "Test like '" + string.Empty + "%'";   <-- do not work
 // bs.Filter = "Test IS null";                       <-- do not work 
 Dgv_Data_List.Columns.Clear();
 Dgv_Data_List.DataSource = bs;
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: The percent sign % is a wild card, so your filter was saying "give me everything".  Try `Test = ''`

Comment: Actually, I had already tested it. 
However now it works. Thanks for the help